# Windows Forms DataPoint: Is it possible to set an image as a DataPoints background directly without having to write it to a file first?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-visualization, mschart

The Forms DataPoint class contains a property for setting the path to an image used as the background for the DataPoint. I obtain an image from an internal symbol provider and it seems wasteful to have to write the image to a file before using it. I looked at deriving from DataPoint but there doesn't seem to be anything relevant I can override. Any suggestions for setting the DataPoint background to the image directly?

Comment: Can't you just set the BackImage to the symbol provider directly?

Comment: That is the property I was looking at, however BackImage is for setting the path to an image. I would prefer to have a property or method that accepts a bitmap so I don't have to write every icon to file before I can use it (the graph is dynamically updating and there will be a large number and variety of icons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the base Chart class has an Images property, this can be populated with images without needing to write them to file first.

The images can then be set to the MarkerImage property of DataPoint.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.images%28v=vs.110%29.aspx